# React toggle class on click. Mapping list items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping items of object to list items.
I would like to get changed class for specific item i clicked.

Currently all mapped items get class "Done" on click.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Tasks from '../data.json';


function List() { 
  const tasks = Tasks.Tasks
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {
          tasks.map((item, i) => (
            <li
              className={isActive ? 'Done': ""}
              key={i}
              onClick={toggle}
            >
              {item}
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default List;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving the class `Done` whenever `isActive` is set to true, to each of your list item.
Maybe try to initialize `isActive` like this:

```
const [isActive, setActive] = useState(null);
const toggle = (i) => {
  setActive(i);
};
```

and then give the `Done` class this way:

```
<li className={isActive === i ? 'Done': ""} key={i} onClick={() => toggle(i)}>{item}</li>
```

You can also store all of the active index in an array by initializing `isActive` this way:

`const [isActive, setActive] = useState([]);`

and then write your hook :

```
const toggle = (i) => {
  if (isActive.indexOf(i) === -1) {
    setActive([...isActive, i]);
  }
};
```

then you can do the following in order to give the class to all of the divs you clicked.

```
<li className={isActive.indexOf(i) !== -1 ? 'Done': ""} key={i} onClick={() => toggle(i)}>{item}</li>
```